# Android - Building a cursor from string SQL

Tags: android, sql

I have the following code

```
QBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE + " LEFT JOIN " + DATABASE_TABLE_CHANNEL_TYPES + " ON (" + DATABASE_TABLE + "." + KEY_CH_CHTYPE_ID + " = " + DATABASE_TABLE_CHANNEL_TYPES + "." + KEY_CH_CHTYPE_ID + ")");
String sql = QBuilder.buildQuery(new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EPG_NAME, KEY_FAV, KEY_CH_CHTYPE, KEY_CH_COU_ID, KEY_CH_CHTYPE}, "", new String[] {}, null, null, KEY_NAME + " DESC", null);
```

This code provides regular SQL query (String SQL)...

I don't know hot to execute this String and return Cursor... Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SQLDataBase.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: `db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)` I tried with this but where do I put query than?

Comment: And what your common sense tells you? Create an activity, create a separate class to manage your data with database, and call this class from your activity.

Comment: sorry it was misunderstanding I meant query as string `"SELECT _id, channel_name, epg_name, favorite, type FROM channels LEFT JOIN channel_types ON (channels.id_ch_type = channel_types.id_ch_type) ORDER BY channel_name DESC"` build with query builder...

Comment: I have tried with `db.rawQuery` but I got error: `Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 148, numColumns = 5
`